# How do I prevent mina from removing images uploaded on production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

Im using mina to deploy my rails 4 app. When ever I `mina deploy` it clears out all the images that have been uploaded to my app. How do I stop this from happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure your uploaded assets end up in the shared directory, similar to the way your database.yml is done.

For example, our assets are all stored in public/system, so we have a line that looks like this:

```
set :shared_paths, %w[
  files
  log
  private
  public/system
  tmp
]
```

Then, when you run `invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'` those directories will be linked to the root of your current directory, if they exist in the shared directory (you can create/populate them if they do not).